# Mysql Create table shows ERROR 1005 errno 150

Tags: mysql, innodb, foreign-key, table

I am trying to make a junction table, but I getting a ERROR 1005 errno 150

```
CREATE TABLE 61furiousFistPokemon(
cardNumber int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
pokemonName VARCHAR(12),
type VARCHAR(10),
stage VARCHAR(10),
evolvesFrom VARCHAR(12),
HP INT,
retreatCost INT,
weakness VARCHAR(10),
weaknessAmount VARCHAR(5),
resistance VARCHAR(5),
resistanceAmount VARCHAR(5)
);

CREATE TABLE cardTags (
tagId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
tagName VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE 61furiousFistPokemonTags (
tagId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
pokemonCardNumber int,
tagName VARCHAR(60),
FOREIGN KEY (pokemonCardNumber) REFERENCES 61furiousFistPokemon(cardNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (tagName) REFERENCES cardTags(tagName)
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

tagName column in table cardTags  is not defined as primary key and you are declaring foreign key FOREIGN KEY (tagName) REFERENCES cardTags(tagName).

Comment: Although you did not provide a solution, +1 for revealing root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Very often it happens, when the foreign key and the reference key don't have same type or same length.
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018584/error-code-1005-cant-create-table-errno-150) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quick fix: Just add a `UNIQUE KEY` on `tagName` in the `cardTags` table

## SAMPLE SCRIPT

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS testing;
CREATE DATABASE testing;
USE testing
CREATE TABLE 61furiousFistPokemon(
cardNumber int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
pokemonName VARCHAR(12),
type VARCHAR(10),
stage VARCHAR(10),
evolvesFrom VARCHAR(12),
HP INT,
retreatCost INT,
weakness VARCHAR(10),
weaknessAmount VARCHAR(5),
resistance VARCHAR(5),
resistanceAmount VARCHAR(5)
);
CREATE TABLE cardTags (
tagId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
tagName VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY (tagName)
);
CREATE TABLE 61furiousFistPokemonTags (
tagId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
pokemonCardNumber int,
tagName VARCHAR(60),
FOREIGN KEY (pokemonCardNumber) REFERENCES 61furiousFistPokemon(cardNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (tagName) REFERENCES cardTags(tagName)
);
```

## SAMPLE SCRIPT EXECUTED

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS testing;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE testing;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE testing
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE 61furiousFistPokemon(
    -> cardNumber int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    -> pokemonName VARCHAR(12),
    -> type VARCHAR(10),
    -> stage VARCHAR(10),
    -> evolvesFrom VARCHAR(12),
    -> HP INT,
    -> retreatCost INT,
    -> weakness VARCHAR(10),
    -> weaknessAmount VARCHAR(5),
    -> resistance VARCHAR(5),
    -> resistanceAmount VARCHAR(5)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE cardTags (
    -> tagId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    -> tagName VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    -> UNIQUE KEY (tagName)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE 61furiousFistPokemonTags (
    -> tagId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    -> pokemonCardNumber int,
    -> tagName VARCHAR(60),
    -> FOREIGN KEY (pokemonCardNumber) REFERENCES 61furiousFistPokemon(cardNumber),
    -> FOREIGN KEY (tagName) REFERENCES cardTags(tagName)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!